# cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

want to use the ESP IDF application while building the code in ESP-IDF I am getting this error:

[image]

This is the OpenSSL version in my system.

```
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)
```

Comment: Ask the packaging system which package provides `libssl.so.1.1`, and install that package.  Start with `dpkg -S libssl.so.1.1`.

Comment: The error messages in the linked image don't seem to be in any way related to the error message in your title